# for loop in method vue js and replace caract

Tags: php, loops, vue.js

I must display data that I set in my user model, I get the info from the database but encode in HTML format.

I have already tried a lot of things like deserialize my JSON to put in the right format but I still have the output in pure HTML.

```
public function ReadUserData($action) {
    if (strcmp($action, "read") == 0) {
        global $f3;
        $user = $this->db->exec("SELECT
                    users.username,
                    users.email,
                    users.mobile
                    FROM
                    users");
        return json_encode($user);
    }
}
```

**and in my vue js i have :**

```
methods : {

    getDataUsers: function() {
        axios.get("http://localhost/?action=read")
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response.data.error) {
                app.errorM = response.data.message;
            } else {
                //app.users = response.data.users;
                app.users = "{{ @users }}";
                console.log(app.users);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Actually my output is in HTML format :/

```
[{&quot;username&quot;:&quot;toto&quot;,&quot;email&quot;:&quot;toto@gmail.com&quot;,&quot;mobile&quot;:&quot;0676565443&quot;},
{&quot;username&quot;:&quot;jojo&quot;,&quot;email&quot;:&quot;jojo@gmail.com&quot;,&quot;mobile&quot;:&quot;0678654534&quot;},
{&quot;username&quot;:&quot;jojo&quot;,&quot;email&quot;:&quot;jojo@gmail.com&quot;,&quot;mobile&quot;:&quot;0678654534&quot;}]
```

" where replace by &quot :/

I was thinking if it was possible to directly loop through the method and replace the "& quot" with real double quotes?

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

You must return json header from backend:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

And accept json in front end:

```
axios.post("/", {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                data
            })
```

Comment: If i add header('Content-Type: application/json') I have this error : JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data :/

Comment: I can help you via skype if you like